# BufferInputStream not reading the last packet

Tags: android, sockets, io, buffer, file-transfer

i am trying to send an apk file from one device to the other. Basically, the user that is going to send, has a gridview with his installed apps (non system apps) and when the user presses the icon of one of the apps, it will send it to the other device. The file is buffered into smaller packets.

I am doing some sysouts to check what is happening and the sender device is sending X packets meanwhile, the receiver is receiving less than X packets (it dependes on the app that is being sent, so that is why i wrote X). I think it is the last one that is missing.

The length of my buffer is 4096 and that "last packet" is only 2115. On the receiver side, it is not throwing the sysouts that there are after the reading and writing to the file. So the program is getting stuck at reading instruction. **My question is Why this last packet is not being transmited?**

Here is my code.

Client side - the sender of the apk.

```
     public class SendThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            if(clientSocket==null){
                clientSocket=new Socket(serverIP,porto);
                System.out.println("client comm - Created the client socket..");
            }

            System.out.println(" client comm, i am here in the send thread, going to create the outputstream object");
            if(out==null){
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println(" Client COMM SEND THREAD - JUST created the outputstream .");
            }


            File apkToSend=new File(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte [4096];
            BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(apkToSend));
            int count;
            int total=0; 
            while((count=bis.read(buffer,0,4096))!=-1){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.write(buffer,0,count);
                total+=count;
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Client Comm send thread - already sent this ammount : "+total);
            }

            bis.close();
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("clientComm send thread - Just sent the message ! i am after the out.writeOBject. Not saving it to a string yet.");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the server side - the device that receives the file..

```
    public class ReceiveThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(socket==null){
                socket=serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("serverComm - accepted the socket from the client.");
                out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject("Hello client, i the server, sending you this message because i want to. SO that you unlock from the input stream creation");
                System.out.println("SErverComm Created the output stream and sent a HEllo message to the client ");
            }

            if(in==null){
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            }
            while(!serverSocket.isClosed()){
                try {
                    if(!handshakeDone){
                        System.out.println("server comm receive thread - INSIDE THE WHILE CICLE, before the in.readObject");
                        String message = (String) in.readObject();
                        System.out.println("ServercomM receive thread - just did the handshake message control");
                        handshakeDone=true;
                    }else{

                        System.out.println("server comm receive thread - INSIDE THE WHILE CICLE, before the in.readObject");
                        File apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/testeReceiveServerComm.apk");
                        byte[] buffer = new byte [4096];
                        BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(in);
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(apkReceived);
                        int count=0;
                        int total=0;
                        while((count=bis.read(buffer,0,4096))!=-1){

                            fos.write(buffer,0,count);
                            total+=count;
                            System.out.println("Server Comm receive thread - already received this ammount : "+total);

                        }
                        ;
                        System.out.println("Already received everything ! ");
                        fos.flush();
                        bis.close();
                        fos.close();
                        System.out.println(" server comm receive thread - already read the object !!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    }

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a BifferInputStream, as you are buffering yourself by reading 4092 bytes at a time. You can try bringing it up to 8192, but no need to double buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous fallacies here.

1. > the sender device is sending X packets meanwhile, the receiver is receiving less than X packets

   You aren't counting packets, so you can't possibly know that. In any case the number of 'packets' received has nothing to do with the number sent in TCP. What is important is the number of *bytes*, and there is no evidence here that you've lost any bytes at all. All you've seen is that the last read returned 2115 bytes when your buffer size is 4096. All that means is that the size of the input file is N*4096+2115 instead of being a multiple of 4096.
2. You're using an `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` but you're only sending bytes. You can use the socket's own input and output streams for that: no need to pay the extra overhead of byte streams.
3. You're pointlessly wrapping a `BufferedInputStream` *around`the`ObjectInputStream`. It should be the other way around.
4. The `Thread.sleep()` in tour code is literally a waste of time. And space. Remove it.
5. You're flushing the output stream after the socket is already closed. You should close the *output* stream, not the input stream, and closing it makes the flush redundant.
6. You must also be catching and ignoring an `IOException` resulting from the `flush()`, unless you're extraordinarily lucky and there is nothing to flush. I don't see how that is possible as your file isn't a multiple of your buffer size.
7. You're using `while (!serverSocket.isClosed())` as a termination test for reading from the accepted socket. This makes no sense whatsoever.
8. Your receive thread both accepts and processes a single connection. This makes your entire server single-threaded. There should be a thread for accepting, and threads to handle each accepted socket.

You need to have a good look at a networking tutorial, for example the Custom Networking section of the Oracle Java Tutorial. This is no way to write networking code.

Comment: I had those thread.sleep's because there was someone telling me to do so here on stackoverflow. I tried it out , but obviously it didn't work.
The condition in your 7. is just so that i can receive multiple files, and so that i am always listening for something. If i didn't have that condition how would the server always be listening ?

Also, i am not closing the socket..

Comment: The server would always listen in the separate accept thread. What you're doing in the loop mentioned is reading data from a socket you've already accepted. It doesn't have anything to do with the `ServerSocket` whatsoever. Sleeps in networking code are literally a waste of time. And your server doesn't 'keep listening'. It only handles one connection. Unless you implement (8) above.

Comment: But if I implement that suggestion, when should i start the thread to receive ? I can't predict when i am going to be receiving data, that is why i thought that the thread to receive something should always be "active"

Comment: You should start the receiving thread for a socket as soon as you accept the socket. This is shown in practically every networking tutorial and example I've ever seen, and in any case I consider it rather obvious.

Comment: Ok, i was kind of confused when i posted this, and some of the code that was in my post was changed even before you answered. I am kind of ashamed of some things that are up there. Thank you for your input. You already helped me on other questions.
I just still dont understand why i shouldn't be using the ObjectOutputStream... I am sending an initial String just to say hello on both sides, and then i send an apk file.